# Change an Existing Column to Computed and Persisted without dropping the table/column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, computed-field

I wanted to change an Existing Column in SQL Server to computed and persisted without dropping the table/column.

I have an auto-incrementing `ID` and another column `ReportID` which is formatted with this computation:

```
ReportID = 'RPT'+{FiscalYear}+{0s}+{Auto Incremented ID}
```

For example:

- for ID = 1, 2, ...., 10, 11, ..., 100, 101
- ReportID would be `RPT2122000001`, `RPT2122000002`,..., `RPT2122000010`, `RPT2122000011`, ..., `RPT2122000101`, `RPT2122000102`

Previously, we were doing this in an "after insert" trigger -  compute the value and update the row. But by doing this some of the ReportIDs are getting duplicated when the load is high and the Reports are generated by different users in parallel.

So, to solve this I thought to change the existing column to a computed column with the `'RPT'+{FiscalYear}+{0s}+{Auto Incremented ID}` but the problem is that I want the existing data to be remained the same. Because if the computation runs now, all the previous year's data will be modified with current financial year which is wrong.

When I try directly by setting the computed value in Management Studio, it is also internally running the drop and add back in the background.

I saw plenty of answers but they were not satisfying enough.

I tried to create a new column with the computed value and then try to rename, which also it is not allowing.

**Edit 1**

*Error:*

```
Computed column 'ReportID' in table 'Tmp_wp_tra_report_creation' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic
```

**Edit 2**

*Financial Year Calculation:*

```
(select (case when ((select top 1 a.Pc_FromDate from wp_pc_calendar a where a.Pc_FromDate>=getdate())<=getdate()) then (select top 1 b.Pc_FinYear from wp_pc_calendar b where b.Pc_FromDate>=getdate() order by b.Pc_FromDate asc ) else (case when ((select top 1 c.Pc_FromDate from wp_pc_calendar c where c.Pc_FromDate<=getdate() )<=getdate()) then (select top 1 d.Pc_FinYear from wp_pc_calendar d where d.Pc_FromDate<=getdate() order by d.Pc_FromDate desc ) else 'No Records' end) end) as finyear)
```

Also, Is there a way without creating a new Column?

Comment: **(1)** Add a **new** column that is computed and persisted and check if everything is OK. If so **(2)** drop the existing column and the trigger, and **(3)** rename the new column to the old column's name. You cannot change an existing column into a *computed* column "in place" - you need to create new / drop existing - no other way, sorry

Comment: As an aside, you can make it into a computed column, but there is little to no point to making it a persisted column. If you need quick lookups on the column, index it; this will persist it as a matter of course. Persisted columns are really only needed now for floating-point columns to make them deterministic, which is an unusual case. The option to persist a column made more sense in previous versions of the engine, when you couldn't just index computed columns.

Comment: @marc_s: SQL is not allowing to rename, copy or change it to computed persitent  column

Comment: @JeroenMostert : The old data should not change, immediately I make the column computed, it computes the whole old data and makes all the previous Fiscal Year as Current Fiscal Year. I need the old data untouched

Comment: Then you *cannot* use a computed column as-is. At the very least it must do something like `COALESCE(alreadystoredvalue, newcomputedcolumn)` in order to take the old data if it's present. `PERSISTED` does *not* mean "compute only once and leave untouched"; if you change the data later, the computed column will update. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=318af18f3c364150f3ed69e382bf12c7). Note that a computed column cannot refer to values outside the row either, save for unstable hacks like invoking a function, which can render the table inconsistent.

Comment: TL;DR a computed column must be deterministic, meaning it must not depend on when you calculated the value but only on the current state of the row. If it does depend on when it was calculated a computed column is not the correct approach. If the trigger isn't cutting it for you, either rewrite it to be transactionally safe or use a stored procedure rather than a simple `INSERT`, possibly in combination with things like sequences to do safe, reliable generation of incremented values.

Comment: Are `FiscalYear` and `Auto incremented ID` part of the row? If so, you can use a computed column. If not, then not. You can add it retroactively by extracting it from the current ID to make the use of a computed column possible, of course -- the main thing is that they should not change later (for any given row).

Comment: May be the answer lies where you are calculating {FiscalYear}.can you show us ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh: I have updated the FiscalYear query for your reference.

Comment: @SreeramNair if Financial Year Calculation returns 'no records' then what will be your report_id?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur If FY has nothing, then it would be RPT000001 without the 2021, but this should never happen because PC_FromDate will always have value

Comment: Can you show us the trigger so we can see why you are getting duplicates, as there maybe a simple fix. Also it looks like the financial year is based upon the current date - you could store this in a parameters table and schedule a job to update it once a day/month/year as needed. Also the reportid looks like it is a display value and could be calculated in the display code.

Comment: @SteveFord I am just updating the `ReportID` by getting the Max ID, But when this statement runs simultaneously by 2 users both will return the same Max ID and resulting in duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think to approach this by:

1. Renaming the original column
2. Creating the new computed column that uses the original column and fails over to a computation if the original column has no value (is null).

Like:

```
-- === Setting up some data for testing
drop table if exists test_reports
create table test_reports (
  id int identity(1, 1),
  fiscal_year int,
  report_id varchar(15)
)
insert test_reports (fiscal_year, report_id) values (2122, 'RPT2122000001')
insert test_reports (fiscal_year, report_id) values (2122, 'RPT2122000002')
insert test_reports (fiscal_year, report_id) values (2122, 'RPT2122000010')
insert test_reports (fiscal_year, report_id) values (2122, 'RPT2122000011')
insert test_reports (fiscal_year, report_id) values (2122, 'RPT2122000101')
insert test_reports (fiscal_year, report_id) values (2122, 'RPT2122000102')

-- === Rename the existing column to something else because it will start to 
-- === contain nulls and the nulls may break existing code.
exec sp_rename 'test_reports.report_id', 'original_report_id'

-- === Add our new, computed column that checks the original column
-- === for a value and uses the original value, if available.  Otherwise,
-- === the computed column is an actual computation.
alter table test_reports add report_id as (
    coalesce(original_report_id,
             'RPT' + convert(varchar, fiscal_year) + right('000000' + convert(varchar, id), 6)))


insert test_reports(fiscal_year) values (2123)

select * from test_reports
```

Comment: The problem here is, we don't have a column which stores fiscal year, The fiscal year is calculated in the computed value itself

Comment: Looking up the fiscal year is a significant addition to the requirements of the question. Calculated columns need to be calculated using data from the row itself.  I would suggest continuing to use a trigger to assign, at least, the fiscal year to the row.  Then you'll be able to use a calculated column and avoid duplicate report ids.

Comment: I will try and let you know. But should i use the Instead of, Before or After Trigger?

Answer (score 1):

In my example

Try this,

```
drop table if exists test_reports
create table test_reports (
  id int identity(1, 1),
  col1 varchar(10),
  report_id varchar(15)
)
insert test_reports (col1,report_id) values ('çol1', 'RPT2122000001')
insert test_reports (col1,report_id) values ('çol1', 'RPT2122000002')
insert test_reports (col1,report_id) values ('çol1', 'RPT2122000010')
insert test_reports (col1,report_id) values ('çol1', 'RPT2122000011')
insert test_reports (col1,report_id) values ('çol1', 'RPT2122000101')
insert test_reports (col1,report_id) values ('çol1', 'RPT2122000102')
```

> Step 1

, Rename old column

```
sp_rename 'test_reports.report_id', 'Oldreport_id', 'COLUMN';
```

> Step 2 : Get max auto incremented id column value.
>
> Step 3 :

```
ALTER TABLE test_reports

    ADD report_id AS CASE
                         WHEN id > 6
                         THEN 'RPT' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(id AS VARCHAR)
                         ELSE Oldreport_id
                     END;
```

> Step 4 Try new insert

```
 insert test_reports (col1) values ('çol1')
    select * from test_reports
```

You can use your own logic for fiscal year, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

since you are calculating fiscal year , you can put the fiscal year calculation inside a scalar function and use it in your computed column :

1. make  function for fiscalyear calculation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fiscalyear(@currentdate AS datetime)
RETURNS int 
AS BEGIN 
   @fiscalyear int = <yourlogic here >
 RETURN @fiscalyear
end
```

however in your fiscal year calculation , you should make it depends on an input param date (instead of getdate()) and in your computed column you pass something like reportdate or insertdate for that row.

because if your calculation is based on the getdate() , the value for computed column will be changed next year for the same row. and that is not what you want.

also using a function would be considered as non deterministic and computed column can't be persisted.

then follow up what other said as well:

2. rename old column :

```
exec sp_rename 'test_reports.report_id', 'original_report_id'
```

3. add another column to save the reportdate

```
alter table tablename
add reportdate datetime not null default (getdate())
```

you can set a default for it and no inserty/update needs to get modified

4. add the new computed column :

```
alter table test_reports add report_id as (
    coalesce(original_report_id,
             'RPT' + convert(varchar,dbo.fiscalyear(reportdatecolumn) + right('000000' + convert(varchar, id), 6)))
```

Comment: we don't have the Report_Date column thats the issue

Comment: @SreeramNair then add that column to your table , see step 3 in updated answer, otherwise you can't go with computed column approach at all.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue as of yours long time back and below solution worked for me.

You might be facing this issue because in case of bulk insert it will just update the value of the column (for all rows) with last updated value, and so you are getting duplicate values.

Considering your existing structure - **after insert trigger**, one of the approach would be to continue using the trigger and try iterating through the INSERTED table

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #T
END

CREATE TABLE #T (
    [Serial] INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[ID] INT
    ,[ReportID] VARCHAR(100) -- data type you are using 
    )

INSERT INTO #T (
    [ID]
    ,[ReportID]
    )
SELECT [ID]
    ,[ReportID]
FROM INSERTED

DECLARE @LoopCounter INT
    ,@MaxId INT
    ,@ID INT
    ,@ReportID VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @LoopCounter = MIN([Serial])
    ,@MaxId = MAX([Serial])
FROM #T

WHILE (
        @LoopCounter IS NOT NULL
        AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxId
        )
BEGIN
    SELECT @ID = [ID]
        ,@ReportID = [ReportID]
    FROM #T
    WHERE [Serial] = @LoopCounter

    /*  write your logic here, you can use @ID to identify your record
        ReportID = 'RPT'+{FiscalYear}+{0s}+{Auto Incremented ID}
    */

    SELECT @LoopCounter = min([Serial])
    FROM #T
    WHERE [Serial] > @LoopCounter
END
```